# Attaching file in a web form portlet

Tags: liferay

I am trying to add a field in web form portlet of liferay to upload a file. Currently I am able to add this field in my form but unable to get the attached file on server/ mentioned location. I am getting a null pointer exception. Below are the changes I have done in 4 files of web form portlet.

## edit_field.jsp

```
   <aui:option selected='<%= fieldType.equals("file") %>' value="file">
   <liferay-ui:message key="file" /></aui:option>
```

## view.jsp

```
 <c:when test='<%= fieldType.equals("file") %>'>
     <tr>
      <td class="order-table-label">
        <label><%= HtmlUtil.escape(fieldLabel) %></label>
     </td>
     <td>
     <aui:input cssClass='<%= fieldOptional ? "optional" : StringPool.BLANK 
    %>' label="" name="<%= fieldName %>" type="file" value="
    <%=HtmlUtil.escape(fieldValue) %>"/>
    </td>
   </tr>
 </c:when>
```

## ConfigurationActionImpl.java

```
  boolean isFileUpload = false;

  if("file".equals(fieldType))
  {
   isFileUpload = true;
   }
  preferences.setValue("isFileUpload" + i, String.valueOf(isFileUpload));
```

WebFormPortlet.java

```
  UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest = 
  Portalutil.getUploadPortletRequest(actionRequest);

  File uploadedFile = uploadRequest.getFile("file");

  String sourcefileName = uploadRequest.getFileName(uploadedFile.getName());
  (Throws NULL pointer exception on this line)

  File folder = new File("\tmp\uploadedfile");

  File filepath = new File(folder.getAbsolutePath() + File.seperator + 
  sourcefileName);

  FileUtils.copyFile(uploadedFile ,filepath);
```

Comment: Do you have solution for this? if so can you please tell me what's the approcah you have followed? i have a same requriement and i am not able to find workaround for ths.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the file in the document library instead of the tmp path, wich is actually complettly out of scope from the portal itself.

do you need the mailing feature of the portlet ? i don't  think that your customizations will work with this use-case

looks like the npe states that there is no file in the request, or not with that name, have you  already looked into that request ?

Comment: I have already mentioned path for document library in portal-ext.properties but the thing is that nothing is being set in request only and I dont need mailing feature, I just want to save the file on server and rest of the information of form in database.How should I get this file in request?